# Interleave numbers from 1 to n, with the same numbers reversed

Tags: code-golf, string, number, integer

#### A simple one:

Take a positive integer **n** less than 1000, and output the integers from **1** to **n** interleaved with the integers from **n** to **1**. You must concatenate the numbers so that they appear without any delimiters between them.

#### Test cases:

```
n = 1
11

n = 4
14233241

n = 26
12622532442352262172081991810171116121513141413151216111710189198207216225234243252261

n = 100
110029939849759669579489399210911190128913881487158616851784188319822081218022792378247725762675277428732972307131703269336834673566366537643863396240614160425943584457455646554754485349525051515052495348544755465645574458435942604161406239633864376536663567346833693270317130722973287427752676257724782379228021812082198318841785168615871488138912901191109299389479569659749839921001
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest submission in bytes in each language wins. Explanations are encouraged.

Answer (score 19):

### JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```js
f=(n,k=1)=>n?f(n-1,k+1)+n+k:''
```

#### How?

This is pretty straightforward but it's worth noting that the string is built from tail to head. An empty string at the beginning is appended last and allows the coercion of the final result to a string to happen.

Below is the detail of the recursion for `f(4)`:

```js
f(4) =                                            // initial call
f(4, 1) =                                         // applying the default value to k
f(3, 2) + 4 + 1 =                                 // recursive call #1
(f(2, 3) + 3 + 2) + 4 + 1 =                       // recursive call #2
((f(1, 4) + 2 + 3) + 3 + 2) + 4 + 1 =             // recursive call #3
(((f(0, 5) + 1 + 4) + 2 + 3) + 3 + 2) + 4 + 1 =   // recursive call #4
((('' + 1 + 4) + 2 + 3) + 3 + 2) + 4 + 1 =        // n = 0 --> end of recursion
'' + 1 + 4 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 1 =              // final sum
'14233241'                                        // final result
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,k=1)=>n?f(n-1,k+1)+n+k:''

console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(4))
console.log(f(26))
console.log(f(100))
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda n:''.join(`x+1`+`n-x`for x in range(n))
```

Thanks to ovs for 4 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ6WurpeVn5mnkVChbZignZCnW5GQll@kUKGQmadQlJiXnqqRp6n5v6AoM69EIU3DRPM/AA)

Explanation:

```python
lambda n:''.join(`x+1`+`n-x`for x in range(n))
lambda n:                                      # anonymous lambda taking one parameter n
                 `x+1`+`n-x`                   # `x` is repr(x) which is equivalent to str(x) for integers less than INT_MAX
                            for x in range(n)  # integers x in [0, n)
```

Comment: Two bytes more in Python 3: `f'{x}{n-~-x}'`

Comment: @L3viathan That's a new feature added in 3.6.

Comment: Python 3.6 is not Python 3?

Comment: @L3viathan It is, but it's a specific version. Python 3.5 and below don't have that string interpolation feature.

Comment: It is the most recent version. Generator comprehensions, which you use, were added in Python 2.4, Python 2.3 and below don't have that feature, but you still categorize your answer as "Python 2".

Comment: @L3viathan That's because Python 2.7 is in wide use. The same cannot be said for 3.6 yet. For example, the Ubuntu Main repo only has 3.5. 2.4 was released in 2004; 3.6 was released 5 months ago. There's a stark difference.

Comment: `lambda n:''.join('x+1'+'n-x'for x in range(n))` for 46 bytes .(replace the `'` in the list comprehension with backticks)

Comment: @ovs hey, you can escape the backtick -> `\`\\`x+1\\`\`` renders to `\`x+1\``

Answer (score 10):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 25 bytes

```bash
printf %s`seq $1 -1 1|nl`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19QlJlXkqagWpxQnFqooGKooGuoYFiTl5Pw//9/QwMDAA)

Prints decreasing sequence, number lines increasing and printf joins lines

<del>Space delimited, 20 bytes :
seq $1 -1 1|nl|xargs</del>

Comment: if that is not acceptable i can change it for `seq $1 -1 1|nl|tr -d ' \n\t'` 8 bytes more

Comment: The 20 byte submission is invalid.  My upvote is for the 25 byte submission.

Comment: As Digital Trauma noted, the 20-byte solution is invalid.

Comment: `time printf %s'seq 1000000 -1 1|nl'; grep name /proc/cpuinfo`
`real    0m7.985s
user    0m6.092s
sys     0m0.392s
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz`

Answer (score 8):

-5 thanks to Ørjan Johansen

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f n=do a<-[1..n];[a,n-a+1]>>=show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzYlXyHRRjfaUE8vL9Y6OlEnTzdR2zDWzs62OCO//H9uYmaegq1CbmKBb7yCRkFpSXBJkU@egp5CmqZCtKGOiY6RmY6hgUHsfwA)

Comment: (1) A `do` expression is shorter than `>>=` plus a lambda. (2) However, the `show`s can be combined by using `>>=show`.

Answer (score 7):

## R, 35 bytes

```
n=scan();cat(rbind(1:n,n:1),sep="")
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/#r#@59nW5ycmKehaZ2cWKJRlJSZl6JhaJWnk2dlqKlTnFpgq6Sk@d/0PwA)

`rbind(1:n,n:1)` creates a 2 row matrix with 1 to n in the first row and n to 1 in the second. The `cat` function collapses this matrix, reading down each column.

Comment: Note that this only works in interactive mode, and requires the user to enter `n` on the command line (instead of passing via stdin).

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes, I think that's usually allowed, but I'm fairly new here, could be wrong.

Comment: I think it's generally acceptable, but NB, to run it properly in TIO you have to put the input(s) in the Footer field (and it's always good to include a link!) https://tio.run/nexus/r#@59nW5ycmKehaZ2cWKJRlJSZl6JhaJWnk2dlqKlTnFpgq6Sk@d/0PwA

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Saved a byte using the new interleave built-in as suggested by *rev*

```
LÂ.ιJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53CT3rmdXv//G5kBAA)

**Explanation**

```
L        # range [1 ... input]
 Â       # create a reversed copy
  .ι     # interleave the lists
    J    # join
```

Comment: A user by the name of [rev](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85855/rev) suggested `LÂ.ιJ`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech: I know the consensus now is that we can use features newer than the challenge, but I'm usually hesitant to edit old answers because a new built-in completes the challenge better. There are so many answers in all that could be improved that way :)

Comment: Well, I only was the messenger; possible @rev should post their own answer.

Comment: @JonathanFrech: I didn't mean it as a reproach. Rev did it correctly when he suggested the edit as it is better to edit an existing answer than post a new one whenever a new built-in is made. I really should get better at fixing old answers, at least when suggestions are made.

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
ri,:)_W%]z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UqWOlGR@uGlv1/7@RGQA)

#### Explanation

```
ri   e# Read input and convert to integer N.
,    e# Turn into range [0 1 ... N-1].
:)   e# Increment to get [1 2 ... N].
_W%  e# Duplicate and reverse the copy.
]    e# Wrap both in an array to get [[1 2 ... N] [N ... 2 1]]
z    e# Transpose to get [[1 N] [2 N-1] ... [N-1 2] [N 1]]
     e# This list is printed implicitly at the end of the program,
     e# but without any of the array structure (so it's essentially flattened,
     e# each number is converted to a string and then all the strings
     e# are joined together and printed).
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.times{|x|$><<x+1<<n-x}}
```

### Explanation:

```ruby
->n{n.times{|x|                # x in range [0..n-1]
               $><<            # output on console
                   x+1<<n-x}}  # x+1, then n-x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2uXV52nV5KZm1pcXVNRo2JnY1OhbWhjk6dbUVv7v6AoM69EIS3aJPY/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
jksC_BS
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jksC_BS&input=100)

#### Explanation:

```
jksC_BSQ   implicit Q (=input number) at the end
      SQ   create the range [1, ..., Q]
    _B     bifurcate by inversion, this gives [[1, ..., Q], [Q, ..., 1]]
  sC       zip and flatten result
jk         join to a string
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>65</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to Laikoni:

```
f n=show=<<(\(l,r)->[l,r])=<<zip[1..][n,n-1..1]
```

---

6 bytes saved thanks to nimi:

```
f n=show=<<(\(l,r)->[l,r])=<<zip[1..n][n,n-1..1]
```

---

Previous answer and explanation:

```
f n=concatMap show$concatMap(\(l,r)->[l,r])(zip[1..n][n,n-1..1])
```

There's already a better Haskell answer here, but I'm new to both Haskell and code golfing, so I may as well post it :)

This function zips the list [1..n] with its reverse, resulting in a list of tuples.

```
[(1,n),(2,n-1),(3,n-2)..(n,1)]
```

Then it uses `concatMap` to map a lambda to this list of tuples that results in a list of lists...

```
[[1,n],[2,n-1],[3,n-2]..[n,1]]
```

...and concatenates it.

```
[1,n,2,n-1,3,n-2..n,1]
```

Then a final `concatMap` maps `show` to the list and concatenates it into a single string.

`f 26
"12622532442352262172081991810171116121513141413151216111710189198207216225234243252261"`

Comment: The infix function `=<<` is the same  (within the list monad) as `concatMap`: `f n=show=<<(\(l,r)->[l,r])=<<zip[1..n][n,n-1..1]`.

Comment: 1) Your current solution is only 48 bytes. 2) You can drop the `n` in `[1..n]`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7Y4I7/c1sZGI0YjR6dIU9cuGkjFagJFqjILog319GKj83TydIEMw9j/uYmZeQq2CgWlJcElRQoqCmkK5v8B "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 1) Dang off-by-one errors... 2) Good call!

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 71 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#LYrBDQAwCALfxxQM4f6rUbWGBMhBbKuFYAK0gOas72gGXbuF/0MdSuoB)

### Explanation

```
sssn  ; push 0 - seed the stack with 0 (this will be our 1->n counter, a)
sns   ; dup
tntt  ; getnum - read n (stored on the heap)
sns   ; dup
ttt   ; retr - pull n onto the stack (this will be our n->1 counter, b)
nssn  ; label 'loop'
snt   ; swap - bring a to the top
ssstn ; push 1
tsss  ; add - increment a
sns   ; dup
tnst  ; putnum - output a as a number
snt   ; swap - bring b to the top
sns   ; dup
tnst  ; putnum - output b as a number
ssstn ; push 1
tsst  ; sub - decrement b
sns   ; dup
ntstn ; jez 'exit' if b is 0
nsnn  ; jmp 'loop'
```

The first couple of instructions are needed to set up the stack correctly, Whitespace's input commands write to the heap so we need to copy b (the input value) back onto the stack. We start with a = 0 since it is shorter to declare 0 instead of 1 (saves a byte) and we only need to reorder the increment instruction to cope. After that we just loop and increment a, output a, output b, decrement b, until b reaches 0 (checked after the decrement).

Comment: this could be much more golfed if you removed all that trailing whitespace :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
)&
pX`=
(pl0
id@z
r}Z)
```

#### Explanation:

We read an integer and put it on two stacks.

```
id
r}
```

On one, we call range_up (`Z`), on the other range_down (`z`), then we set a catch mark to be able to return to this place later:

```
  @z
  Z)
```

We then check if the current stack is empty and exit if so:

```
 X`=
  l0
```

Otherwise, we print from both stacks and jump back to the catch mark:

```
)&
p
(p
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
{seq 1,_<>seq _1,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyfFvO/uji1UMFQJ97GDsSIN9QxrP2fm5iZV80VbWQWW5PGVfsfAA)

This is an anonymous function that takes input from the stream.

#### Explanation

```
{seq 1,_<>seq _1,1}               Anonymous function, takes integer n from the stream
        <>                        Interleave
 seq 1,_                            the range 1 .. n with
          seq _1,1                  the range n .. 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 29 bytes

```matlab
@(n)printf("%d",[1:n;n:-1:1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkadZUJSZV5KmoaSaoqQTbWiVZ51npWtoZRir@T8xr1jDyEzzPwA)

Comment: My implementation was so, so much longer! Nice! =)

Answer (score 3):

**Scala, 43 bytes**

It's not the best but it's my first code golf.

```
n=>1.to(n).foldLeft("")((s,x)=>s+x+(n-x+1))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 20 bytes

```perl6
{[~] 1..*Z~($_...1)}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NVBLaxNRFN7Pr7iLIklTp/e8zyFU3Lpx5UojoukIBduEPEQp7V@vX0JlYLjn9b2O@6n99nG9HO7/tjfrze3Ubl4evzx/bTSOl5@fZxffxnGk@dML5u8P0/7QbtrF5YeP43pz/2N2vbpdXM/H3eaw2c14vhyOwPuEreWw/fX9oS3OJ8vh52b3ev32XZut7h62x8PVavqzndaH6Xb@OLR2t28n@tniPJxftf/Tq3buDE8vD@CmgWgYTi8dSFmE9bVmH4id2dDCwBgFBfekKkrqFETkxGQkpPgEL0aHMOmURZXcAx1gsCir8AnkFZ56B3XvXCWVWmHlXhaliUYx9QJSdWIgSSZpBlk6eRpFKmXKieEkiCk7cxRLJGsEWzh7GEcoZwhXsPSAwujCXiKeoh5i7uJuEq6SLlLO2h1evCtbqViqWqiZq5tpmGqaaBlbN/jFn1EJuoqpYcuxHbhKXJcykJAJUBnoAhYFm4HVwR5QkVBTwlCG3KCSoVagWqHe4MLhJuAq4a6Y4RTpwzXDvSAFRRqGVBzpBFJKpFXESI6QYK9TwFkaZV5uFYqzc76d/gE)

With an input of [100000](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9Xx1dF6tgqKenFVWnoRKvp6dnqFn7vzixUgEsb2gAAv8B) this takes roughly 10 seconds, including compilation and printing the output.

### Expanded:

```perl6
{                # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [~]            # reduce using concatenation operator ｢&infix:«~»｣
                 # (shorter than ｢join '',｣)

    1 .. *       # Range from 1 to infinity

    Z~           # zip using concatenation operator

    ( $_ ... 1 ) # deduced sequence starting at the input
                 # going down to 1
}
```

The `Z~` needs the `~` because otherwise it generates a list of lists which will stringify with spaces.

There is no need to limit the Range starting at 1, because `Z` stops when any of the input lists run out.
This saves two bytes (a space would be needed after `$_`)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 61 bytes

```
(int n)->{for(int i=0;i<n;System.out.print(i+1+""+(n-i++)));}
```

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: We allow anonymous functions, so `(int n)->{//for loop}` should work here.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Yep!  You can potentially put your `System.out.print()` in the last statement of the for loop, but it gets complicated because you are using `i` twice (and you need to increment it in the expression).

Comment: I put the print inside the loop and incremented i at the last possible place then checked it with the Test cases to make sure it worked, thanks @NathanMerrill

Comment: don't need the parens around `int n` iirc. Or `int ` for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
RṚĖVV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/0cOesI9PCwv4fbn/UtEYh61HDnEPbDm171DBXQeHhju1AroJvYoFCTmZeto5CcWpBYlFiSapCfmlJQWlJsUJSpUJeajlQMrVY7/9/Qx0FEx0FIzMdBUMDAwA)

#### How it works

```
RṚĖVV  Main link. Argument: n

R      Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 Ṛ     Reverse; yield [n, ..., 1].
  Ė    Enumerate; yield [[1, n], ..., [n, 1]].
   V   Eval; convert each flat array to a string, interpret it as a Jelly program,
       and yield the output. This concatenates the integers in each pair, yielding
       a flat array of integers
    V  Repeat the previous step, concatenating the intgegers from before.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 61 bytes

```
#(let[a(range 1(+ 1 %))](apply str(interleave a(reverse a))))
```

Literally does what is asked. I believe it can be outgolfed by a less trivial solution.

[See it online](http://ideone.com/Ml9Hix)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <strike>36</strike> <strike>35</strike> 29 bytes

```
for(;$argn;)echo++$i,$argn--;
```

Saved one byte thanks to Jörg Hülsermann.

Saved six bytes thanks to Christoph.

Comment: Uhm... `for(;$argn;)echo++$i,$argn--;` ?

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
⟦₁g↔ᶻczcc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rJHTY3pj9qmPNy2O7kqOfn/fyOz/1EA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₁           [1, …, Input]
  g↔ᶻc       [[1, …, Input],[Input, …, 1]]
      z      Zip
       cc    Concatenate twice
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 41 bytes

```
pryr::f(for(i in 1:x){cat(i);cat(x-i+1)})
```

`pryr::f()` creates a function that takes one input. Loops over `1:x` and prints each element of `1:x` along with each element of `x:1`. Prints to STDOUT.

Comment: +1, nice use of `pryr`

Comment: @ssdecontrol its pretty much staple replacement of `function(x)` :)

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @Luis*

```
:tPv1eVXz
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=%3AtPv1e%22%40V%26h&inputs=10&version=20.0.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a number, N
:       % Create an array from 1..N
tP      % Create a reversed copy
v       % Vertically concatenate the two
1e      % Reshape it into a row vector
V       % Convert to a string
Xz      % Remove whitespace and implicitly display
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah! I thought there was a function that removed whitespace but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 20 bytes

```
ywo1@"­ñykPjñkògJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@19Znm8o7aB0aO3hjZXZARJZjIc3Zh/elO71/7@RAQA)

Explain:

```
yw                    ' Copy the input number (for looping later)
  o1                 ' Insert a 1 under the input (on a newline)
     @"               ' [Copy register] number of times
       ­ñ      ñ       ' Do the thing inside of this loop
        ykP           ' Copy the current line and line above it, and paste above both
           j        ' decrement the current (top) number, and increment the one below
               k      ' Go to the top line
                ògJ   ' recursively join all of the lines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 17 bytes

```
....1I>sO)su.@?(O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@68HBIaedsX@msWleg72Gv7//5sCAA)

cubified:

```
    . .
    . .
1 I > s O ) s u
. @ ? ( O . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Pushes `1`, reads in the input (`I`), then enters the loop which swaps the top of the stack, outputs it, increments, swaps, outputs the top of the stack, decrements, and stops if the top of the stack is 0.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>63</s> 54 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(dotimes(i n)(format t"~a~a"(1+ i)(- n i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r/FfIycxNyklUSNPUyMlvyQzN7VYI1MByEnLL8pNLFEoUapLrEtU0jDUVsjU1NBVyANSQPDfyEzzPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 16 bytes

```
{,//$r,'|r:1+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/79aR19fpUhHvabIylBbsaLWyOz/fwA)

Comment: `r,'|r:` -> `+|:\ `

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 5 bytes

```
{îkï-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68Lrsw@t1//835DLhMjLjMjQwAAA)

#### Explanation:

```
{      Run a for loop over implicit input
 î     Push 1 based index of loop
  k    Push inputted number
   ï-  Subtract 0 based index of loop
       Implicitly output all this joined together
```

Comment: I've been able to find 13 programs of length 5 which yield the same result: `╒{ïí,`, `╒{ïk,`, `╒{íï-`, `╒{kï-`, `╒{┐í,`, `╒{┐k,`, `╒x{î\ `, `{îïí,`, `{îïk,`, `{îíï-`, `{îkï-`, `{î┐í,`, `{î┐k,`. However, I have not been able to find any program of length 4 or less. I haven't done a full search, but it is very probable that 5 bytes is optimal for MathGolf.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 41 bytes

```forth
: f 1+ dup 1 do i 1 .r 1- dup 1 .r loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCoAgEETvfcXgNRQN6VDQzyhWEChS328TiHmat292N8R8H3IPX5SyIMCM8E@CgY84GSrDyKrIV4wJa1GCIyA3CMcF3jFcHujt723vp7l5YlcYrdsjYm3KCw)

#### Explanation

Loops from 1 to n and outputs the index as well as n-index in a right-aligned space of size 1 (forces no space after output)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f               \ start new word definition
  1+ dup 1        \ set up arguments to loop from 1 to n
  do              \ start loop
    i 1 .r        \ output the index in a right-aligned space of size 1
    1- dup        \ subtract 1 from current value of n and duplicate
    1 .r          \ output new n in right-aligned space of size 1
  loop            \ end loop
;                 \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse-2002](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/), <strike>32</strike> 30 bytes

-2 moved conditional to start of loop `(z.^ ... )` instead of `(... z.0>^)`

```
?n:n.z:(z.^a.1+a:a.!z.!z.1-z:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y80vLU41MjAw@v/fPs8qT6/KSqNKLy5Rz1A70SpRT7EKhAx1q6w0/6v8NzQwAAA)

**Explanation:**

```
?n:                                 ~ get input and store in n
   n.z:                             ~ copy n into z
       (z.^                         ~ stop if z equals 0
           a.1+a:                   ~ add 1 to a
                 a.!                ~ print a
                    z.!             ~ print z
                       z.1-z:)      ~ substract 1 from z
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ɾḂYṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiyb7huIJZ4bmFIiwiIiwiMVxuNFxuMjYiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
ɾḂYṅ
ɾ     # range of [1,input+1]
 Ḃ    # dupe and reverse
   Y  # interleave
    ṅ # join with no spaces
```

Comment: `:Ṙ` can be substituted into `Ḃ`, saving one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), <s>46</s> 32 bytes

```lisp
(\(N)(} ,(m u({ ,(z(1to N)(to1 N
```

An anonymous function that takes an integer and returns a string. Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2). Example session:

```lisp
tl2> (\(N)(} ,(m u({ ,(z(1to N)(to1 N
(() (N) (} , (m u ({ , (z (1to N) (to1 N))))))
tl2> (def interleave-numbers _)
interleave-numbers
tl2> (interleave-numbers 4)
"14233241"
```

#### Explanation

```lisp
(\(N)(} ,(m u({ ,(z(1to N)(to1 N))))))
(\                                   ) ; Lambda function
  (N)                                  ; that takes an integer N:
                 (z              )     ;  Zip together these two lists:
                   (1to N)             ;   Numbers from 1 to N
                          (to1 N)      ;   Numbers from N to 1
             ({ ,                 )    ;  Right fold on list/string concatenation
         (m u                      )   ;  Map unparse (convert to string) to each number
     (} ,                           )  ;  Left fold on list/string concatenation
```

The reason for the different folds is that right fold is more efficient, but by default it starts with an empty list, which when concatenating strings would make the result a list of charcodes instead of a string. Left-folding strings, by contrast, results in a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
R;R@Z♂iεj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@x9kHeQQ9WhmU@a5rVn//5sAAA), or [run all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#e9Sz4H@QdZBD1KOZTZnntmb9f9Sz0Dfzf7ShjomOkZmOoYFBLAA)

Explanation:

```
R;R@Z♂iεj
R          range(1, n+1)
 ;R        duplicate and reverse
   @Z      swap and zip
     ♂i    make 1D
       εj  join with empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 18 bytes

```
[:|Z=Z+!a$+!b-a+1$
```

Explanation

```
[:|       FOR a = 1 to n
Z=Z+      Add to Z$ 
!b$+      a cast of the loop counter as string
!b-a+1$   and a cast of (n+1) minus the loop counter to string
          Z$ is printed implicitly at the end of QBIC
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
Row@Riffle[x=Range@#,Reverse@x]&
```

*thanks Martin*

Comment: `#+1-x` is more efficient than `Reverse@x`. ------- Note: `Row` does not even make it a string, just a formatting. It looks identical to a string on some platforms, but it show as multiplication sign between on Wolfram sandbox. However it takes less bytes than `ToString/@(""<>...)` or `""<>ToString/@...`.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*1 byte removed thanks to Martin Ender*

```
ri:X{_)X@-}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UaRVRHa8Z4aBbq/r/v5EZAA)

#### Explanation

```
ri               e# Read integer n
  :X             e# Copy n into variable X
     {     }%    e# Map over the array [0 1 2 ... n-1]
      _          e# Duplicate
       )         e# Add 1
        X        e# Push n
         @       e# Rotate
          -      e# Subtract
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>34</s> 30 bytes

`{for(i=1;i<=$1;i++)printf i$1-i+1}`

```
{for(;i<$1;i++)printf i+1$1-i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@1@dll@kYZ1po2JonamtrVlQlJlXkqaQqW2oYqibWfv/vwkA)

Comment: could shave 4 with `{for(;i<$1;i++)printf i+1$1-i}`

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 28 bytes

**27 bytes code + 1 byte for `-a`.**

```perl
map{print$_,"@F"+1-$_}1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#@5@bWFBdUJSZV6ISr6Pk4KakbairEl9rqKenEv//v6GBwb/8gpLM/Lzi/7qJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Braingolf v0.7, 18 bytes

```
VR.MUvU&,R{vMR}>&_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#zRprc9vG8Tt@xVmJTMCiaEJ9fGBFt5mMM01mnGTc2NMZmtHA4EFCDQIoDqSpSdK/7u699w4ARaoOpx9s8e729va9e4vLmmpN2D0j@bqumpYkze02yPhktinTtqoKs9TQ1SalcjGtioKmbV6VZnlF/72hgRpUbFIn7Z0Z1rRJ2qrR47yljcCtJ5qkXFVrPVqjrQ0NgrRIGCNMnBCK/6NZQODEjNzc3NIW0K1vbkJGi2xM8nJFd2KdkDwjOctL1iZlSkOxMiasyFOqAAjgbzdNSdr7mgoEUWiIm@QCFOOdAKqmtYOqtr9pHUUBQikInQwRGASAKv3AyJwslkG6aRoxhuE0oOUK/n6TFIwGdUMZbbbUTKRVuQUCzbihMGR2nbVNXt6aIWVpUtvV9aZo8xogLAL2Ia/NIM/s0SwvKILLCgH3UwNqLqrK7slAuvfOzG1D6ereDPmaEJzgLivwby5tbhowVAqOAkFfWm3E4Wdnkuj0LmnkcCe2Blz9XLttyIQ22@ZeaV1MYVUImgmhu5TWLXmbFBv6smmqZoaBJK0CrbRXGmq7HZMsB/2A7VAQ/0ocp3ZpkNCFkHhA9UKr26QIxY8x0focA4KtQARGCnKW6xGZA28zhVwu6h0OsQJ6MV1yAEBEKNCuJi/jJecVJro7JnVVFzRrw6i7ka@FXcLZoZRfkyuXcLT2gsTGI11@COH0cO0/xJHgJb@9s8BxL/CVBLYCcI84QAQ9Zx20yx45zKbLwXSQ1s7p4gSly5ADjSWMp7FQaOa2qN4nhdzMAtcG2MJEm6XcC/62pjdZAvG@YWEpdQtnX8FfNSvDFCEf7yAowOIz@Hc9J6VhtyTnJNc85ORiTuIOayV5/nxOcjVSmCdJXUPAC/MoUIiMsXgQJZKAWlL0JxAAbyB1sZD/p9zT0Aw/NQodYjimDILODoIFz3nMyRdtuEP5gYGW9P5dpJgSRjCBRJXehaOf3y0mz94tvxyNid2YNM23Zb3hOqTc/3eRxdhHjmAYSMolSXKzRoZIyyM7KckD9zBCFACRARCEcj/MRWSJ92ytmpW31SpO05Zy2nI824smjaKO7s32nd3uytbuVDqGZaxfngDCtFpBAJJ2jC19J41nB1FoSoRiX8wF43xDhANhYDcZP7BTQIgdaBdGO2TytRMq@2KX4@kXIRT5145tAkZ7IAPbEaRgtCRysB3zJGxHPLGiNZ2H7ZRMxO4GkX0xxs6EzslYEjoje5xwpXCJ6uLFhiGYTGGCy3@xWwbK4e65CUC1d0vD6dgmCFuvybh4D5GdkbJqeTLXBmOW5jLFq2EUSN1zKRo0KTf30a8jIsyO/56NDB5c8GjvWjkz1lQAl5Grh/03g9GKzMkgyvfsKk@EU2v/MpiaHEeezBEmwqewq8lM0FQtr0xi66i8HLJK7Lputzzbj9HhvYftpWHbqAuytsOYmb3UaUATig2wS@oeKk3@7aPSOpUXx1MTLFFNCbkpdbH4lOjak6OwGyOZ1g0eUQHEVhbcXKW/Wo4EeDgaTf5V5WW4SO@aMBfkQaCK4/iPcXwl8UwjG/2l@Kx3XIrzZstlNOYBaj4aRe6pfq1BupnelBwzH68ooiRH17hmkwWOrskl2p7rg@bTu6YoMtwrREcVop5X7isCp2drZyMCN0PBowykNhY4txzENFfvQiYzK1ETq5aYEXulMLlSHvvuHbbx7umEmGuVulq49mOxK1uTuGXykEDSqnuSpn@/cwibWXlAyFKYPth7mQN8NtJHKVl1QW5GtoADnDJdaC6gakERfegOw9NfdIgTAALffA@3Gr@UyHEeIZ1EsocYTc5BfD2WYCTi@T4RS1IWsmzzAsCyW0TlojEwRXJgrYFnvsDPztmMnLMzqMx572NMFjk@YomKPY74wsZq7/7u8PO3ffw48aHXNbgxWp8jHs84gDXiFrEvYj4qCMqAtlg@oFIpQk6FbwP7hPOFEo514q7P/Weky1HduOnCfKldVxtWF2S8Tw8Dt28hcN6n6FwslcBE82JoEUcsgWVgTbdAuqofyElWLUomK@3NB4j8qZKDgemKajLqibmm7Ipc4FwBm3YS945aFANwIcO1HUwgsfJC807cj/B0X6C/M3y51Y8DeanqMdWzevnDN6hj1QuLeCj6GEZB0oVeKehj432v5/jtSFc24E88D0S9bIiC7c6nrunjRfaLJ/yPSQIHER51XGPqRJMDeUL0MeuHFu/jU@hAOOoTq/F9wDtgRdODLI3j4ZRea2H49vQW62Cge4Fb2EYQLCKXIqsgZFsdI9EG@/uCxJotzbMgyUJcqjTFEZrJF86hpo532uqdTdf2znIw9WmPupkIsaIyM3hmD@Y3EQxt@yOPnDA5aei62lJlTwP8ILpeDdJ1Ilss6a4dVCeWOSIPTE86n7VnTiXcg7@vSjrTQjKojbB4DHH5X/9/8n/p828CTtfK/kcJvLYS6FjhHsP5xyOjvxND@Be7Cdy4BVkeXV9/tgPSivUd8NNnO6BNejmoH50g87VoQ7sNdqU6HBuqpoWiR8IPJEePph8VTSX96NVQPm5sB6KOhlj5hysRrUQPP776sw1LGp0XlfpKNw3q0rV5PF2y3Wd2fkai3jxA1LGK7d5AcVHTIfciPpbgXV/Rs84HCrh/9kInu35oaq2ZuVyzB9gWNa@4yPPEFfEoZcZQR3v9VXP90@1VM3F8kfXyweiue5GOeJ/MO5MXuKnapbRD6xFZANH7naXXvZgNWaDvGJgNp6Uh7sMRhztLaF5tvnr57Q9vzvCFwze/ePibjg86jfZc1ZClupiOT6wufZot7kM@Y95VH@ki69UFnjU3wqyroK@Ugna27dF9idB7GzV60vBaDD3d/Hz2QK/9PQV0FNechtOBb15qeZVnmbMNagiJLOg5j0PjnIfJQEL5u20Yin6haVvza9tQf2pfkyVWjV2ObS5/LGYzLhypVv/uXR6VPPp8hIeo4cQxcB0a8JjDw/X3vzPd8WF0T4@l@6@PLGxsIoh4BTH9HSP/QpGoPg0ZTPhN0c7d8stIPx@wH77Mvr4XR0XOWtfHiwHUFw/0y49MqH53yHt2NElWq7GTYsdOAo72XlScxnE21B41l/nN2mu69bQMBtzc7l0OduwGyESyfX5a2WZgGc0q334eAXtuv5CPJftOe0hQSCLPTiuR9aY4jTDEQUfI4fK0cmCb96eRgzjoCDn8fFo51NXH08hBHHSEHM5P7BfV6kR@wQ86SA7u64ZuF92/8z1REkMkdj@TXDvXSFUjdr4tvOiD8oH@ooDkS2ZxlH3JZd9kfaGeR/wI0/wT9TkbkXPxZCja86IKP9HqfU6lXz26b8N4rcyft6Nro3qCDVcA9wnhdhHPlu6LzuHWt6z7d6qzid6b7S3h1cWj//3K0e9Per919709OeiVSRTs@axqjHjgNUmw551Ir4d0Pp7rJxflShutee6FCxD5edJtCaBl9G2Hf7sNWLVpUjofjUaf3r6evHqzffN0/PqX7avXv714evMJpgNpnBJuwq0O0EefPl396b8)

#### Explanation:

```
VR.MUvU&,R{vMR}>&_  Implicit input of n to stack
VR                  Create new stack then return to main
  .M                Duplicate n and move duplicate to new stack
    U               Replace stack with 1-n, where n is last item on stack
     vU             Replace 2nd stack with 1-n
       &,           Reverse second stack
         R          Return to main
          {   }     Map loop, runs for each item in the stack
           vMR      Move to next stack, move last item to main stack
               >    Cleanup after loop
                &_  Print all items in stack with no delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-P`, <strike>11</strike> 8 bytes

*Saved 2 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```
õ í1õU)c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BWhcNrQ4FkuWby//9GZgq6AQA)

### Explanation:

```
õ í1õU)c
õ              Range [1...Input]
  í            Pair with:
   1õU           Range [Input...1]  
      )c       Flatten   
-P             Join into a string
```

Comment: Use the `-P` flag to save a byte. [Link](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SDtVfUgdylj&input=MjYKLVA=)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! When I wrote it, I tried [this](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SDtVfUgdylj&input=MjYtUA==) and assumed it wasn't joining due to a bug.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BWhcNrDQ9vDdVM/v/fyExBNwAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 37 bytes

```
param($n)-join(1..$n|%{$_,($n-$_+1)})
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
RżU$FV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x90dE@oilvY////zQA)

Explanation:

```
         Example: n = 6
R        Create a range from 1 to n             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  U$     and a reversed copy of that same range [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 ż       and interleave them                    [ [1, 6], [2, 5, ... ]
    F    Flatten the list                       [1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4 ...]
     V   And Eval: Jelly code consisting of only numbers would simply print those numbers,
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 20 bytes

```
.+
$*__
\B
$.`$.'
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivp82lohUfzxXjxKWil6Cip84Vz/X/vyGXCZeRGZehgQEA) Includes test cases. Explanation: Each pair of numbers sums to `n+1`, so we convert `n` to unary and add 1. Then, we match between each pair of `_`s, counting the number of `_`s to the left and right. This generates the pairs of numbers. Finally we delete the `_`s now that they've served their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>16</s> 12+3 = <s>19</s> 15  bytes

```
l:n}:n1-:?!;
```

Input is expected on the stack, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag.

Thanks to @TealPelican for pointing out a very clever way to save 4 bytes by using the size of the stack itself - on the first iteration it'll be 1, then 2, then 3... That way, the first number in each pair manages itself, no manual incrementing required!

Previous version:

```
1:n1+$:n1-:?!;$!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P8cqr9Yqz1DXyl7R@v///7plCiYA)

Comment: Surprisingly I came up with something fairly similar before checking the answers for ><> but you can save a few bytes by replacing the; 1+$ with } and then removing the final; $! at the end to come up with this; l:n}:n1-:?!;

Comment: [`ln:n1-::?!;`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PyfPKs9Q18rKXtH6////umUKJgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, <s>25</s> 21 + 1 = <s>26</s> 22 bytes

Takes input from stdin, without a trailing newline.

Runs with the `-n` flag:

```
print++$x.$_--while$_
```

4 bytes saved thanks to Dada.

Comment: It doesn't work for numbers greater than 9. That's because the precedence of `.` is higher than the one of `+`. Adding parenthesis around `$_+1` would solve this. Also, you can remove the parenthesis around `$_--`. But even shorter, you can take the input without final newline (with `echo -n` for instance), and then you can do `print++$x.$_--while$_`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

```c
a;f(n){for(a=1;n;a++)printf("%d%d",a,n--);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ROk0jT7M6Lb9II9HW0DrPOlFbW7OgKDOvJE1DSTVFNUVJJ1EnT1dX07r2f25iZp5GIlCxhpEZiA8A)

Comment: You can save a byte by putting the `++` on the `a` in the `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda n:''.join("%d%d"%(x+1,n-x)for x in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSl1dLys/M09DSTVFNUVJVaNC21AnT7dCMy2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1VI09T839BUWZeiUaahpEZkAMA)

Port of [Mego's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123467/48934).

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-mP`, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
°Us+N´
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=sFVzK060&input=NAotbVA=)

```
           :For each U in the range [0,input)
°U         : Prefix increment U
  s        : Convert to a string
   +       : Append
    N´     :  Postfix decrement the (singleton) array of inputs
           :Implicitly join and output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 53 bytes

```cs
a=>{for(int i=0;++i<=a;)Console.Write(i+""+(a-i+1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY@7asNAEEVr7VcMqnYRtiTn0axlMKkCSZME0qRZ1qswYM2EfdgYoW9XVoWLFHF35x7mwLVhZdm7OQWkb3i/hOgGDfZoQoA9jCBCNBEt7G1Epi1S3EEP3Wy63dizl7kA7BpdVbjtjFZPTIGPbv3pMTqJVVlW0qywapXS06yvuhPjAV4NklQwiqKXrdLF39/yi0qlF3Z/g20eb8C2af6loqhrSGR5GNyyoYcLJzibnCNDCm65PfCZAOknRVHX2ZhdJ@fj@oOfKd5t5NX95szhBclJlXeKaZoffgE)

Uses an [Action delegate](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1) to pull in the input and not require a return.

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {
    for(int i = 0; ++i <= a;)           // initialize i and increment until a
        Console.Write(i + "" + (a - i + 1));    // output i and "inverse" of i
                                                    // empty string required to set as string
                                                    // parentheses required because C# is dumb and can't figure out what a minus sign is supposed to do without them
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
fun g(e:Int)=(1..e).forEach{print("$it${e-it+1}")}
```

[Try it online](https://pl.kotl.in/SJciljRL4)

Older version, the one above also prints it, the one below produces a string.

```
fun y(n:Int)=(1..n).joinToString(""){"$it${n-it+1}"}
```

[Try it online!](https://pl.kotl.in/Sk8U6cCLV)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
(∊⍪,⌽)⍕¨∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NRR9ej3lU6j3r2aj7qnXpoxaOOGY96N/9Pe9Q24VFv36O@qZ7@j7qaD603ftQ2EcgLDnIGkiEensH/0xQMudIUTIDYyAxIGBoYAAA)

Explanation:

```apl
(∊⍪,⌽)⍕¨∘⍳  ⍝ Monadic function train
       ⍕¨∘⍳  ⍝ Generate integers from 1 to input, convert each to string
             ⍝ Call this vector "X"
  ⍪          ⍝ "Table" X, making a single-column matrix
   ,⌽       ⍝ Reverse X and concatenate it with the above table
             ⍝ This results in a two-column matrix with integers from
             ⍝ 1 to N and N to 1 side-by-side
 ∊           ⍝ "Enlist" the above - left-to-right, top-to-bottom,
             ⍝ recursively concatenate all items in the matrix
```

Comment: Don't forget to claim your [bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/43319)!

Comment: here's a shorter one: `∊⍕¨⌽,⌸⌽⍳⎕`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 32 bytes

```sh
repeat $1 printf $[++i]$[$1+1-i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/KLUgNbFEQcVQoaAoM68kTUElWls7M1YlWsVQ21A3M/b///9GBgA)

I like trying to beat Bash+coreutils with pure zsh, but sadly that is not the case here.

---

Cooler, but one byte longer (**33 bytes**):

```sh
a=({$1..1})
<<<${(j::)${(n)a}:^a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/0VajWsVQT8@wVpPLxsZGpVojy8pKE0jlaSbWWsUl1v7//9/IAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
řĐ↔Žǰ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MwjEx61TTm69/iG//8NDQA)

```
ř          implicit input (n); push [1,2,...,n]
 Đ         duplicate top of stack
  ↔        flip the array at the top of the stack
   Ž       interleave the two arrays
    ǰ      join the contents of the array to create a string; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 12 bytes

```
Rsrp[ul,s`u]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@ouKggujRHpzihNPb/fyMzAA)

This one generates the `1..N` series on the stack, and it generates the `N..1` numbers by manipulating an accumulator on the backup cell.

```
R             - Generate range of 0..N (where N is from STDIN)
 s            - Save the upper limit to the backup cell
  rp          - Reverse the stack, delete the "0"
    [      ]  - While the stack isn't empty
     u        - Print next number in the range
      l,s     - Load backup cell, decrement and save
         `u   - Increment and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 90 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(n int)(o string){for i:=1;i<=n;i++{o+=Sprintf("%d%d",i,n-i+1)};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjejMnML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jTyFDLzSjQ18hWKS4oy89I1q9PyixQyrWwNrTNtbPOsM7W1q_O1bYMLgJIlaRpKqimqKUo6mTp5upnahpq11kWpJaVFebVQG7zAhoKs1NBUqOYKAGnKydNI0zDU1ETimaDwjMxQuIYGBkA-1MQFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>33</s> 22 bytes

```julia
~x=join([1:x x:-1:1]')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADArywSpLCBG9FhoT5iHjyumEkUePLr1pwmvkkC1d5b3eIlWTviCpUnYvKj6WcoWqa93JKflLUahI@sEJogqH8GHSEsCPOKQNZ60z8)

1. The forward and reverse sequences are collected from ranges.
2. [This method of interleaving arrays in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087644/18431399) can be adapted for code golf.
3. <s>The `print` command is [vectorized with the "dot" operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators) so that no delimiters are shown.</s>

- -9 bytes thanks to MarcMush: avoid reshaping the array
- -2 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace `print.` with `join`

Comment: I think `~x=print.([1:x x:-1:1]')` works

Comment: You can also use `join` instead of `print.()`

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
[:;],.&<&":&>:&i.-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o62sY3X01GzUlKzU7KzUMvV0/2typSZn5CukKZjAGIYG/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)!

```
Y\,ayWVRVy
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJZXFwsYXlXVlJWeSIsIiIsIiIsIjI2Il0=)

---

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
(Y++,a)WVRVy
```

How?

```
(Y++,a)WVRVy  : One arg(integer n)
     a        : First arg
    ,         : Inclusive range from 1
  ++          : Increment
 Y            : Yank
         RV   : Alias for unary reverse
           y  : Yanked range
       WV     : Weave two iterables together, alternating their items
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIoWSsrLGEpV1ZSVnkiLCIiLCIiLCIyNiJd)

Comment: [10 bytes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJZXFwsYXlXVlJWeSIsIiIsIiIsIjI2Il0=)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 52 bytes

```
#(apply str(mapcat(fn[i][(inc i)(- % i)])(range %)))
```

Concatenates pair-wise integers (head and tail of the seq).

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.7, 39 bytes**

```
x=''.join(`i+1`+`n-i`for i in range(n))
```

Comment: I think you must either use `input` or make this a lambda. Assuming the variable exists in the workspace is not acceptable I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 9 bytes

```
SD_],sm`s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=SD_%5D%2Csm%60s&input=20&warnings=0)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 52 bytes

As a traditional function:

```
f[x_] := StringJoin[ToString /@ Riffle[Range[x], Reverse[Range[x]]]]
```

As an anonymous function

```
(x = Range[#]; StringJoin[ToString /@ Riffle[x, Reverse[x]]]) &
```

As a code block that accepts the input in the variable n

```
x = Range[n]; StringJoin[ToString /@ Riffle[x, Reverse[x]]]
```

The code is pretty simple -- generate the list of integers with Range[], interleave this list (using Riffle[]) with a copy of the list that has been reversed, then convert all the integers to strings and concatenate them with StringJoin[].

Could have done it in 30 bytes if we were allowed to leave the answer in the form of a list (thus, {1,4,2,3,3,2,4,1} rather than "14233241"). Also, in the hypothetical Mthmtca with short command names it would have been something like 21 bytes.

Performance is tolerable for n <= 1,000,000. I didn't test past that.

Comment: This should be a function that takes an integer argument, rather than having a `4` hardcoded.

Comment: This isn't golfed either, which makes it invalid

Comment: @cat if you think you can write it more concisely, please do so. If you can't, why do you think it's not golfed?

Comment: Yeah, `f[x_]:=StringJoin[ToString/@Riffle[Range[x],Reverse[Range[x]]]]`, I think I counted the close braces right from my phone. Either way I know for a fact that MMA doesn't rely on whitespace, and I can say that as a communiry member

Comment: None of these are 52 bytes, even with whitespace stripped. I get 56 bytes for the middle one (the last one not being valid).

Answer (score 0):

### R, <strike>43</strike> <strike>39</strike> 37 bytes

This is an anonymous function.

```
function(n)cat(rbind(1:n,n:1),sep="")
```

It's 35 bytes if I use `pryr::f()` like in the other answer:

```
pryr::f(cat(rbind(1:n,n:1),sep=""))
```

but needs to be installed (Enter `install.packages("pryr")` in the R console).

Comment: You could save some bytes by not defining `s` and just using `1:n` directly.

Comment: you can also save a couple bytes by removing the curly braces from your first answer

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 67 bytes

A simple one, just for the collection :)

```
n=input()+1
i=1
s=""
while i<n:
    s+=`i`+`n-i`
    i+=1
print s
```

Comment: you can use ``while i<n:s+=`i`+`n-i`;i+=1`` to golf off some bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 15 bytes

```
{?\"!\{$.(.@).!
```

Embiggened:

```
   { ? \
  " ! \ {
 $ . ( . @
  ) . ! .
   . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@19tH6OkGFOtoqeh56Cpp/j/vwkA)

Answer (score 0):

### LOGO, 48 bytes

```
to f :n
for[i 1 :n][(type :i :n+1-:i)]show "
end
```

Define a function `f` that when invoke with parameter = number `n`, print the result string.

Answer (score 0):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), 9 bytes

```
;[>+:<:-]
```

Simple: Read a number from stdin to the current cell; While the current cell is not zero, go to next cell (initially 0), increase it, output its value, go back, output that value and decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
n->{for(int i=1;n>0;System.out.print(n--+""+i++));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xa8QwDIX3/AqTySHEJKV0MXfQoQcdOt3YdlBzds5pogTJOThCfrury9hFQk@8770eblD1l9/UDsCsPiDgmgWMjjy0Tp3W2xQuymuRFBZ2y@blZwit4ghR1v4dxaTPkQJ2n98KqONizU7Kq0PC6rj6iXZ7ODQWj7U93zm60UxLNLN4osaqKvO8DGVZSIJNvXQySwyDeSWCOxuO5GDUO9kI7g3aq@YH2nj9LmU7R2YGYieHZqH8zxhQ51@YC76w2bal1NR1/Rjp6SU9p@YP)

-1 bytes thanks to Sara J!

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY4xa8MwEIV3/wrhScJY2KF0EQlkaKBDp4xNh6sjOXJs2dzJgWD829WLxy533Dve914HDyi76z01PRCJL/BhyXyIFh00VpyWx@ivwkmWRFBmzab5t/eNoAiR1/Yd2CTPEX1ov38EYEtqyU7CiX0K5WFxI252v69NOFRGnZ8U7aDHOeqJTVGGsizyvPBFwQkmddxJz9H3@ogIT9IU0cIgN7Jm3Ac0N0kvtHbyk8u2FvUESJYPSUqZ/xF9kPkl5IxXJlvXlOqqql4j7d7TW6r/AA)

Comment: @SaraJ thanks, I forgot about the for-loop trick

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 44 bytes

```
{n->(1..n).joinToString(""){"$it${n-it+1}"}}

{n->                                          // n is Int input
    (1..n)                                    // range from 1 to end
          .joinToString("")                   // join items with no separator
                           {                  // transform by
                            "$it${n-it+1}"    // current number and number from end of range
                                          }}
```

Lambda that takes an `Int` and returns a `String`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6/CsIwEMb3PsUROtwhDXZwKbTOgpu@QMAop/FSyrVLybPH0A5@6@/794kaWPLiArCon4J3i@8AL6IEzQA3nVhe0OdVmgFba4XsO7Lc407QGFpNzVoXA@uhTSal/JwFvo4FCdYKivb@cVboASfvHlcWX@i5A3M0ZDWWQaTNO5ZeDYL/P7hFiaqUTz8)

Comment: [42](https://tio.run/##RY6xCsJAEET7fMVypNhFcpjCJmBSWQi2fsChF1yMe@HYpAn37ecRC6edeTPzDjqx5NVNwKI@Tt6tvgO8ihI0PdyFFc55k6bH1lohO4Z4cY/XNscCoKlZ6@KyHtpkKKU8LgIfx4IEWwVFv@55KT2A0bvnjcUXd@jAHA1ZDWUMac/@P@COUJXy6Qs) (btw it's basically identical to the other kotlin answer)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 17 bytes

```
[znddn1-d0<M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2T2P7oqLyUlz1A3xcDGNzal2Lfi/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 13 chars, 26 bytes

```
{∊k,¨⌽k←⍕¨⍳⍵}
```

How to use & test:

```
  f←{∊k,¨⌽k←⍕¨⍳⍵}
  f 1
11
  f 26
12622532442352262172081991810171116121513141413151216111710189198207216225234243252261
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 47 bytes

```
=f(n)
~temp i=n
-(l)
~i--
{n-i}{1+i}{i:->l}->->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/q9rl6Zhoqlr9982TSNPk6uuJDW3QCHTNo9LVyMHyM3U1eWqztPNrK021AYSmVa6djm1unZA9f8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
çK^↑Ñ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=874b5e18a5&i=1%0A4%0A26%0A1000&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 36 bytes

```arturo
$[n][""loop 1..n'x->~"|n-x-1||x|"++]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?qN4hwZ)

```
$[n][             ; a function taking an argument n
  ""              ; place an empty string on the stack
  loop 1..n'x->   ; foreach x in 1 to n...
    ~"|n-x-1||x|" ; interpolate x and n-x-1 into a string
    ++            ; append it to the string on the stack
]                 ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
R1+DrsZZ.J
```

##### Explanation

```python
R1+DrsZZ.J  # Implicit input                  STACK (example for n=10)
R1+         # range(0, n) + 1                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   Dr       # Duplicate and reverse           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
     sZZ    # Swap and zip together           [[1, 10], [2, 9], [3, 8], [4, 7], [5, 6], [6, 5], [7, 4], [8, 3], [9, 2], [10, 1]]
        .J  # Join each inner list            ['110', '29', '38', '47', '56', '65', '74', '83', '92', '101']
            # J flag joins the final list     '1102938475665748392101'
            # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
OYax$a
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJPWWF4JGEiLCI0Il0=)

```
OYax$a
 Y     # Interleave
  ax   # [1, n]
    $a # With [1, n] reversed
O      # Join
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RḲI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZLgx7u2OS5pDgpuRgqsmCxoYEBhAkA)

##### Explanation

```python
RḲI  # Implicit input       ->  4
R    # Range: push [1..n]   ->  [1,2,3,4]
 Ḳ   # Bifurcate this list  ->  [1,2,3,4]  [4,3,2,1]
  I  # Interleave           ->  [1,4,2,3,3,2,4,1]
     # Join and output      ->  "14233241"
```